# How to get number of arguments in a macro?

Tags: tex-core

I'm writing a package and I need to get the number of arguments in the macro. Say, user has to define a macros

```
\def\usermacro#1#2....
```

Then he calls

```
\dosomestuffdefinedinmypackage
```

and this command takes `\usermacro` and uses it in a way depending on the number of arguments it has, so I need to find a way to know it.

Preferably without using another package, I what to understand how does it work instead of learning a spell. Thanks!

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/305806/2388

Comment: there is another question on site  in general if you allow all the definitions possible it's not really feasible to do this in tex.

Comment: oh I was just about to search for it but @UlrikeFischer had a head start

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, this relies on changing `\newcommand`... One could build something with `\meaning`.

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz if you know the original macro was defined with newcommand yes but in general with delimited arguments and catcode other `#` etc you really can't tell. Also typically you need the effective use eg you want to know `\section` is used with arguments even though `\meaning` will tell you it has none.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know... But at least in the simple case we can build something.

Comment: The task is not trivial at all. E.g., arguments might be delimited by hashes that are not of catcode 6: `\expandafter\def\expandafter\testA\expandafter#\expandafter1\string#2{#1/blabla}\typeout{\meaning\testA}\def\testB#1#2{#1/blabla}\typeout{\meaning\testB}\typeout{meanings \ifx\testA\testB are equal\else differ\fi}\stop`  Here the macros `\testA` and `\testB` do exactly the same but are considered different: ```\catcode`\Y=6\relax\def\testA#1#2{}\def\testBY1Y2{}\typeout{\meaning\testA}\typeout{\meaning\testB}\typeout{meanings \ifx\testA\testB are equal\else differ\fi}\stop```

Comment: Interestingly parameter-text and definition-text containing implicit parameter-characters doesn't matter: ```\let\para=#\def\testA#1#2{arg1: #1 arg2: #2}\def\testB\para1\para2{arg1: \para1 arg2: \para2}\typeout{\testA{1}{2}}\typeout{\testB{1}{2}}\typeout{\meaning\testA}\typeout{\meaning\testB}\typeout{meanings \ifx\testA\testB are equal\else differ\fi}\stop```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following defines the macro `\getnumargs` which takes two arguments. The first is an arbitrary macro, the second the macro which should store the result.

It'll store the number of arguments taken by the first macro in the second.

**Caveat:** This only gets how many arguments exactly that macro will take, not more not less. It'll also fail if the macro takes delimited arguments. A few examples where it is technically right, but most likely doesn't return what you had in mind are included.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\edef\getnumargs@ifmacro
  {%
    \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\getnumargs@ifmacro@
      \noexpand\getnumargs@meaning\relax\noexpand\getnumargs@ifmacro@true
      \detokenize{macro:}\relax\noexpand\getnumargs@ifmacro@false
  }
\def\getnumargs@ifmacro@true#1\getnumargs@ifmacro@false#2{#2}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\getnumargs@ifmacro@
    \expandafter#\expandafter1\detokenize{macro:}#2\relax
  {}
\newcommand*\getnumargs@ifmacro@false[1]
  {%
    \PackageError{Alex}{}{Not a macro!}%
    \def\getnumargs@num{0}%
  }
\newcommand\getnumargs[2]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \edef\getnumargs@meaning{\meaning#1}%
      \getnumargs@ifmacro
        {%
          \expandafter\getnumargs@settmp\expandafter{\getnumargs@meaning}%
          \getnumargs@getnum
        }%
      \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#2\expandafter{\getnumargs@num}%
  }
\newcommand\getnumargs@settmp[1]
  {%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\getnumargs@tmp
      \getnumargs@getargs#1\relax##1##2##3\relax{##2}%
  }
\expandafter\def\expandafter\getnumargs@getargs
    \expandafter#\expandafter1\detokenize{macro:}#2->#3\relax
  {#2}
\edef\getnumargs@getnum
  {%
    \edef\noexpand\getnumargs@num
      {%
        \noexpand\the\noexpand\numexpr
          \noexpand\getnumargs@tmp
          \string#1\string#2\string#3%
          \string#4\string#5\string#6%
          \string#7\string#8\string#9%
          .{10}\relax
          -1\relax
      }%
  }

\makeatother

\newcommand\noargs{}
\newcommand\onearg   [1]{}
\newcommand\twoargs  [2]{}
\newcommand\threeargs[3]{}
\newcommand\fourargs [4]{}
\newcommand\fiveargs [5]{}
\newcommand\sixargs  [6]{}
\newcommand\sevenargs[7]{}
\newcommand\eightargs[8]{}
\newcommand\nineargs [9]{}

\begin{document}
\getnumargs\section\tmp
\tmp

\getnumargs\texttt\tmp
\tmp

\getnumargs\emph\tmp
\tmp

\getnumargs\noargs\tmp
\tmp

\getnumargs\onearg\tmp
\tmp

\getnumargs\twoargs\tmp
\tmp

\getnumargs\threeargs\tmp
\tmp

\getnumargs\fourargs\tmp
\tmp

\getnumargs\fiveargs\tmp
\tmp

\getnumargs\sixargs\tmp
\tmp

\getnumargs\sevenargs\tmp
\tmp

\getnumargs\eightargs\tmp
\tmp

\getnumargs\nineargs\tmp
\tmp
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for no reply. I'm trying to reintegrate the code to understand which part does what...

Comment: @Alex If you have any questions leave a comment.

Comment: @Skillmon It also fails with undelimited arguments if a parameter-character differing from `#` is used: ```\catcode`\Y=6\relax\def\nineargsbY1Y2Y3Y4Y5Y6Y7Y8Y9{}\catcode`\Y=11\relax\getnumargs\nineargsb\tmp\typeout{\meaning\tmp}\stop``` But this can be neglected. Who would do that in daily life for purposes other than producing edge cases. :-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [user202729's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625582/4427), here is a much simpler coding:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getnumargs}{m}
  {
    \int_eval:n { \str_count:e { \cs_argument_spec:N #1 } / 2 }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_count:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\newcommand\noargs{}
\newcommand\onearg   [1]{}
\newcommand\twoargs  [2]{}
\newcommand\threeargs[3]{}
\newcommand\fourargs [4]{}
\newcommand\fiveargs [5]{}
\newcommand\sixargs  [6]{}
\newcommand\sevenargs[7]{}
\newcommand\eightargs[8]{}
\newcommand\nineargs [9]{}

\begin{document}

\getnumargs\texttt

\getnumargs\emph

\getnumargs\noargs

\getnumargs\onearg

\getnumargs\twoargs

\getnumargs\threeargs

\getnumargs\fourargs

\getnumargs\fiveargs

\getnumargs\sixargs

\getnumargs\sevenargs

\getnumargs\eightargs

\getnumargs\nineargs

\texttt{\edef\test{\getnumargs\nineargs}\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

The number of required expansion steps is greater than two, but that's not really important. The idea is that if the number of steps is one, good, we can use `o` as argument specifier if needed; otherwise use `e`.

[image]