# Print exact macro definition

Tags: tex-core

Is it possible to print the exact definition of a macro?

For example, the code

```
\def\foo#1{\bar\baz}
\printdef\foo
```

should result with `\bar\baz`.

If we define (as suggested in a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145685/displaying-the-definition-of-a-macro))

```
\def\printdef#1{\texttt{\meaning#1}}
```

then the result is `macro:->\bar \baz`, which is slightly different.

Comment: `def\foo#1{\bar\baz}` and `\def\foo#1{\bar \baz }`  are identical definitions, the space characters are never tokenised or part of the definition, so you can not tell which was used

Comment: When you ask TeX to show a definition, with `\show` or `\meaning`, it will *always* add a space after every control word. The token itself is stored in an internal (and not accessible) way (with a pointer to the name, stored elsewhere), so there's not much you can do. But `\bar \baz ` *is* the exact definition.